# Waiting on transform from base_footprint to map to become available

Tags: ros, amcl-demo.launch, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello There!

I am having a hard time to get the Navigation Stack running on a robot (Turtlebot).

I am Using AMCL for Autonomous Navigation in the View of Rviz.

when i Launch

roslaunch turtlebot_navigation amcl_demo.launch map_file:=/home/sr1/Blk-S-Level-1.yaml

I get a warning

[ WARN] [1407204643.804135907]: Waiting on transform from base_footprint to map to become available before running costmap, tf error:

when i launch Rviz, roslaunch turtlebot_rviz_launchers view_navigation.launch

i dont see anything only black Background. under Global Setting i see Error, No tf.

sorry, haven't got karma>20, so cannot post images

Please, can someone help me out? If anything else is needed, I will gladly post it later.

Thanks in advance :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188894/waiting-on-transform-from-base_footprint-to-map-to-become-available/) by [vinod9910](https://answers.ros.org/users/18770/vinod9910/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2014-08-04

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-08-05**:
Now you have enough karma
In Gloabl setting try to put /map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same problem because when i've saved my map I did it in the tmp directory (like in the tutorial) and then manually transfer it to other directory.

If you did it too i advise you to copy the files again to tmp load it , and save it in other location by:
rosrun map_sever map_saver -f /...your directory goes here.../you_map_name

---

Originally posted by [tal_eldar](https://answers.ros.org/users/23439/tal_eldar/) with karma: 33 on 2015-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

in my Globlal setting i have set is as /Map

i have the photo below of the probem.

[image: image description]

Thanks in advance :)

---

Originally posted by [vinod9910](https://answers.ros.org/users/18770/vinod9910/) with karma: 61 on 2014-08-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-08-06**:
I think you have two topic with the same name map. Try to check it

**Comment by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on 2014-08-06**:
What is your log for amcl saying? Did it load the map correctly? Can you add the param output=
"screen" to the  (out can change screen to log and post the log if you want too